# DT: Link binding is lost after re-rendering the table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am trying to navigate to the next tab by clicking on a link nested in a datatable.

This works fine at first using `Shiny.bindAll`. [Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shiny-bindall/14489/2) you can find an explanation from Joe Cheng regarding the use of the function.

However, when the datatable is re-rendered by filtering the input data via the `selectInput` the binding is lost when switching back from 2 to 1:

[image: result]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "panels",
  tabPanel("A",
           selectInput("sel", "Select", choices = c(1,2)),
           DTOutput("tab")),
  tabPanel("B",
           h3("Some information"),
           tags$li("Item 1"),
           tags$li("Item 2"),
           actionLink("goToTabPanelA", "goToTabPanelA")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF <- data.frame(a = c(1,2),
                   b = c(HTML('<a id="goToTabPanelB1" class="action-button" href="#">goToTabPanelB1</a>'),
                         HTML('<a id="goToTabPanelB2" class="action-button" href="#">goToTabPanelB2</a>')))
  
  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      DF %>% filter(a %in% input$sel),
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$goToTabPanelB1, input$goToTabPanelB2), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", "B")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$goToTabPanelA, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", "A")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Instead of adding a load of full stops to your question in order to meet the minimum amount of text, perhaps consider expanding your question to make it clearer to help people help you.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

Another cleaner approach (as it keeps using the same id's for the links) is to avoid re-rendering the datatable by using `dataTableProxy` along with `replaceData`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame(id = paste0(c("goToTabPanelB1", "goToTabPanelB2")),
                 a = c(1,2),
                 b = c(HTML('<a id="goToTabPanelB1" class="action-button" href="#">goToTabPanelB1</a>'),
                       HTML('<a id="goToTabPanelB2" class="action-button" href="#">goToTabPanelB2</a>')))

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "panels",
  tabPanel("A",
           selectInput("sel", "Select", choices = c(1,2)),
           DTOutput("tab")),
  tabPanel("B",
           h3("Some information"),
           tags$li("Item 1"),
           tags$li("Item 2"),
           actionLink("goToTabPanelA", "goToTabPanelA")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      DF,
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  }, server = TRUE)
  
  tabProxy <- dataTableProxy("tab", session)
  
  observeEvent(input$sel, {
    replaceData(tabProxy, data = DF[input$sel,])
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$goToTabPanelB1, input$goToTabPanelB2), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", "B")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$goToTabPanelA, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", "A")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Initial answer**:

A possible workaround is providing the links (a-tags) with new id's on re-rendering the datatable (see the code below).

**Still I'd like to understand what is going on if the id's are static and the datatable get's re-rendered (therefore I offered the bounty).**

The problem seems similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36418876/9841389).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "panels",
  tabPanel("A",
           selectInput("sel", "Select", choices = c(1,2)),
           DTOutput("tab")),
  tabPanel("B",
           h3("Some information"),
           tags$li("Item 1"),
           tags$li("Item 2"),
           actionLink("goToTabPanelA", "goToTabPanelA")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF <- reactive({
    # force id to update
    tmpId <- as.integer(Sys.time())
    tmpDF <- data.frame(id = paste0(c("goToTabPanelB1", "goToTabPanelB2"), tmpId),
               a = c(1,2),
               b = c(HTML(sprintf('<a id="goToTabPanelB1%s" class="action-button" href="#">goToTabPanelB1</a>', tmpId)),
                     HTML(sprintf('<a id="goToTabPanelB2%s" class="action-button" href="#">goToTabPanelB2</a>', tmpId))))
    
    tmpDF[input$sel,]
    })
  
  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      DF(),
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(lapply(DF()$id, function(x){input[[x]]}), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", "B")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$goToTabPanelA, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", "A")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Related links:

- [Trouble with reactivity when binding/unbinding DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572035/trouble-with-reactivity-when-binding-unbinding-datatable)
- https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1246
- [Text Input in DT::datatable unbinds and I can't rebind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098909/text-input-in-dtdatatable-unbinds-and-i-cant-rebind-it/60153632#60153632)
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shiny-bindall/14489/2